# ControleSend send weird output Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote a script that sends some keystroke to my command line. However, the values are coming out totally messed up. What could be the reasons?

```
BlockInput, on
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
DetectHiddenWindows, on
ControlClick, x660 y391, Notepad
ControlSend, , {Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}, Notepad
Sleep 30
ControlSend, ,  2, Notepad
Sleep 30
ControlSend, , echo stat_id: 78 : SETTING PRICE TO 2 toactivate: %Title% >>  logs.txt{Enter} , ahk_exe cmd.exe
ControlClick, x668 y640, Notepad
ControlSend, , echo  ACTION NEXT (after SETTING PRICE) >> logs.txt{Enter} , ahk_exe cmd.exe
WinActivate, %Title%
Send {Ctrl down}+{Ctrl up}
Send {Ctrl down}+{Ctrl up}
Send {Ctrl down}+{Ctrl up}
Send {Ctrl down}+{Ctrl up}
Send {Ctrl down}+{Ctrl up}
BlockInput, off
ExitApp
Return
```

This is one example of output:

```
at-idec; ho78   B: EFSOETRTEI SNGCR PERENIC ESH TOOOT  2 DOTNOEAC >T>I valotges;. tixqt

echo  ACTION NEXT (after SETTING PREICCEHO)  >A>CT lioogn s.ntexxtt
```

Comment: Was I able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few things to mention

1) You shouldn't be using controlsend to send text to a cmd prompt. Instead, you should be using `Run, % Compsec`. ComSpec is just a shortcut to cmd.exe. So when you do `Run, % Compsec` you're really just passing whatever comes next to the cmd prompt. Example for running ipconfig: `Run, % ComSpec " /k ipconfig"`

To easily remember which switch to use, remember that `/k` will "keep the command prompt open when it's done" and `/c` will "close it after the commands have run".

Also, make sure you understand the difference between [Expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions) and non-expression.
The following lines of code look different, but each line does the exact same thing:

```
Run, % ComSpec " /k ipconfig"
Run, %ComSpec% /k ipconfig
```

2) Instead of writing `{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}{Backspace}`, instead, include how many times you want the key repated after the key name but before the closing curly brace. `{Backspace 6}`. This works for any key.

3) BlockInput can be a dangerous command and, usually, I advise others to avoid it when possible. By using Run ComSpec instead of control send, you remove any need to use BlockInput.

4) The problem you were initially having most likely had to do with the text being sent too fast. Lower the send speed with [SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm).

---

Try replacing this:

```
ControlSend, , echo stat_id: 78 : SETTING PRICE TO 2 toactivate: %Title% >>  logs.txt{Enter} , ahk_exe cmd.exe
```

With this:

```
Run, % ComSpec " /k echo stat_id: 78 : SETTING PRICE TO 2 toactivate: " Title " >>  logs.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to send to the console there are alternatives:

- ConsoleSend() https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/25446-consolesend/
- **Windows 10**: You could try pasting text and then send an Enter. **Older** versions of Windows - Requires additional software: I find Clink to be reliable as you can just `Send ^v` after installing it https://mridgers.github.io/clink/